# mvn release:perform generate a SNAPSHOT ?

Tags: maven, release, snapshot

I'm trying build a RELEASE version of an artifact, but for my surprise when I do a mvn release:perform, a SNAPSHOT version is being published in repository.

Is there some reasons for this behave?

Some people can help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post your answers to the `release:prepare` prompts

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a [release:prepare](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) first?